# How to Change input language of textbox in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change language of textbox to marathi in html file
My code is as follows but it not working

```
<html lang="mr" xml:lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<textarea style="height:200px;width:200px;font-family:Mangal">
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: language or font-family?

Comment: Change language? Users can type whatever they want in there. If you are referring to browser spellcheckers, I don't think you can disable them from your webpage.

Comment: other software is needed if you want to type other language.

Comment: @imulsion, it may be possible to disabled spellcheckers, using the `spellcheck` IDL attribute, but I don’t think spellchecking is relevant here.

Comment: The root element has two conflicting attributes about language. The `textarea` element would inherit the setting, but you need to decide between Marathi and English. The language setting has remarkably little impact on browsers, and it surely does not change the way input widgets work. You should rewrite your question in terms of the the desired functionality. What is “not working”, and how should it work?

Comment: I also tried "mr" value for both attributes, lang and xml:lang, but when I type, english appears instead of marathi...How can I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you meant Font and not language...

first of all, give that `textarea` an `id` and a `class`, for example

```
<textarea id="txtArea" class="textarea" style="height:200px;width:200px;font-family:Mangal">
</textarea>
```

then let's get ride of that bad inline style coding and have either an external stylesheet or inside the `<head>` this:

```
<style>
    .textarea { height:200px; width:200px; font-family:Mangal }
</style>
```

so now it would be clean as

```
<textarea id="txtArea" class="textarea">
</textarea>
```

to change the font, just do:

from javascript

```
txtArea.style.fontFamily = "Arial";
```

from stylesheet

```
.textarea { height:200px; width:200px; font-family:'Arial' }
```

or, if you can't ride the inline styles, add the `id` and call the javascript.

I don't recall if the `font-family:'Arial' !important` gets prioritize from an inline style, but you can also try that.

Comment: we're not here to solve your problems, we're here to help you understand your problem!

Answer (score 1):

It could not be done using html tag attributes, css styles or Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use the Google Input Tools

Install it with Marathi pack and you could start typing in Marathi

http://www.google.co.in/inputtools/

A draw back is that it should be installed on all the systems the application uses.If it's an intranet app then it would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

there is no tags in html which will allow you to type in marathi. You can download specific
tools

http://www.google.co.in/inputtools/

http://t13n.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/blet/docs/help_mr.html

but it will not be specific to certain div or tags it will get applied to every application.