# Textarea 2 languages spell check

Tags: html, textarea, lang

My goal is to have a html ***textarea*** tag which spell checks in 2 specified languages. The lang attribute is great for spell checks in 1 language but I can't find any way to spell check in more languages. I have found this "Use enhanced spell check" option and it would be great if I could turn it on for every guest on my website. Or maybe there is some other way to add second language to spell check?

Thanks!
[Enhanced spell check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBom9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
It turns out that two languages together can be confusing. For example the Latin word "fortus" gets flagged:

[image: flagged spellchecker]

So I don't know if it's such a good idea to do this. [You can't even change the default language](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17571818), let alone two.

**Original Answer**
I don't think you can do this.

Spellcheck is widely controlled by the browser, and some basic browsers still don't have it. Other than turning it on or off, you don't have much control over the language used or if enhanced spell check is on.

And see, Edge doesn't even have enhanced spell check:
[image: edge misspelled word]

You can develop your own spell check instead.

Here's a rudimentary example:

```js
const words = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$('#enter').on('input', function() {
  document.getElementById('m').innerHTML = '';
  this.value.split(" ").forEach(function(v) {
    if (!words.includes(v)) {
      document.getElementById('m').innerHTML += "<li>" + v + "</li>";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>The dictionary is only trained to recognize "one", "two", and "three". Type anything else and it will get flagged:<br />
<textarea id="enter"></textarea></label>
Misspelled words:<ul id="m"></ul>
```

However, the caveat with that is that you can't make it look native for every user.

Here's how Firefox flags misspellings:
[image: firefox misspelling]

And here's Edge:
[image: edge misspelling]

One's spikier than the other. This isn't so large of a difference, but it shows how different browsers have different spellcheckers.